# Overlapping LineString and Polygon returning false in Shapely

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am using shapely to find if a LineString and Polygon overlap.

I have defined the polygon based on the map area that I need to find if points are overlapping in:

```
polygon_map = Polygon([(-126.03561599522513,60.08405276856493),(-65.91842849522513,60.08405276856493),(-65.91842849522513,76.84958092750016),(-126.03561599522513,76.84958092750016),(-126.03561599522513,60.08405276856493)])
```

For the LineString, I have a long list of coordinates in two columns, x and y. I have taken the maximum and minimum coordinates of x and y to generate a LineString.

```
line = LineString([(32.823101,87.988993),(-153.01468,30.001368)])
```

When I plot these on a map, they overlap (as expected)

```
m = folium.Map([61.08405, -66.918], zoom_start=3, tiles='cartodbpositron')
folium.GeoJson(line).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson(polygon_map).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

[Image of map created showing intersecting polygon and linestring]

[image: 1]

However, when I do:

```
line.overlaps(polygon_map)
```

It returns false, and I can't work out why.

I have simplified the LineString to only include the minimum and maximum coordinates as I have hundreds of coordinates in my original dataframe and I'm worried it will take too long to loop through each set of coordinates. I haven't used Shapely before so I'm not sure if this is why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all down to geographic  projections.  As pure cartesian geometry without accounting for curvature of the earth they do not overlap.  (See below image).  **shapely** has no knowledge of geographic projections,  it is pure cartesian geometry.  As cartesian geometric objects this polygon and LineString do not overlap.

Only after setting the CRS does **folium** show these geometries overlapping.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString

polygon_map = Polygon([(-126.03561599522513,60.08405276856493),(-65.91842849522513,60.08405276856493),(-65.91842849522513,76.84958092750016),(-126.03561599522513,76.84958092750016),(-126.03561599522513,60.08405276856493)])  # fmt: skip
line = LineString([(32.823101, 87.988993), (-153.01468, 30.001368)])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon_map, line])
gdf.explore(height=300, width=300)

# gdf.set_crs("epsg:4386").explore(height=300, width=300)
```

[image]